# counting the occurrence of specific words in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the amount of times a list of words is mentioned for each row of the dataframe
using this code

```py
df["Count"] = (
    df['Token'].str.split()
    .apply(Counter)
    .apply(lambda counts: sum(word in counts for word in words))
)
```

with words being the list of words is what i used.

```
words = ['wooly', 'girl']
```

however the code results in getting 0 as a value for each entry, which isn't right.

the data I use is a tokenized list as follows: `['uno', 'dos', 'one', 'two', 'tres', 'quatro', 'yes', 'wooly', 'bully', 'watch', 'watch', 'come', 'come', 'watch', 'git', 'matty', 'told', 'hattie', 'thing', 'saw', 'two', 'big', 'horns', 'wooly', 'jaw', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'yes', 'drive', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'hattie', 'told', 'matty', 'lets', 'dont', 'take', 'chance', 'lets', 'lseven', 'come', 'learn', 'dance', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'watch', 'watch', 'watch', 'watch', 'yeah', 'yeah', 'drive', 'drive', 'drive', 'matty', 'told', 'hattie', 'thats', 'thing', 'get', 'someone', 'really', 'pull', 'wool', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'watch', 'watch', 'come', 'got', 'got']`

this list i turn into a string via `df['Token'] = df['Token'].apply(str)`

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of occurrences of a substring in a string you can do

```
string.count(substring)
```

So, you can apply this function to the column where you have the string:

```
string_occurrences = df.Token.apply(lambda x: sum([x.count(substring) for substing in ['wooly', 'girl']])
```

Then you just need to sum the counts

```
total_occurrences = string_occurrences.sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

To count the occurrence of specific words in pandas dataframe you can use the code below.

```
from collections import Counter
    
def most_common_words(labels, quantity):

    words = [i.split(" ", 1)[0] for i in labels]
    counter = Counter(words).most_common(quantity)
    df = pd.DataFrame(counter, columns=["Word", "Occurrence number"])\
                        .sort_values(by="Occurrence number", ascending=True)
    return df

    
# Identify the most common words
df_most_common_words = most_common_words(words, 20)
print(df_most_common_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

simple to use `defaultdict` or `Counter` from `collections`:

```
words = ['uno', 'dos', 'one', 'two', 'tres', 'quatro', 'yes', 'wooly', 'bully', 'watch', 'watch', 'come', 'come', 'watch', 'git', 'matty', 'told', 'hattie', 'thing', 'saw', 'two', 'big', 'horns', 'wooly', 'jaw', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'yes', 'drive', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'hattie', 'told', 'matty', 'lets', 'dont', 'take', 'chance', 'lets', 'lseven', 'come', 'learn', 'dance', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'watch', 'watch', 'watch', 'watch', 'yeah', 'yeah', 'drive', 'drive', 'drive', 'matty', 'told', 'hattie', 'thats', 'thing', 'get', 'someone', 'really', 'pull', 'wool', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'wooly', 'bully', 'watch', 'watch', 'come', 'got', 'got']


from collections import defaultdict
dict_count = defaultdict(int)
for item in words:
    dict_count[item] += 1
```

Or:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

The return of `Counter` is a dictionary.

```py
df["Count"] = (
    df['Token'].str.split()
    .apply(Counter)
    .apply(lambda counts: sum([counts[word] for word in words]))
)
```

If value in `Token` column is already a list, you needn't use `str.split()`

```py
df["Count"] = (
    df['Token']
    .apply(Counter)
    .apply(lambda counts: sum([counts[word] for word in words]))
)
```